# I will delete my rows for 58000+ rows.And delete rows if more than 5% of variables are NA

Tags: r, database, missing-data, delete-row

My dataframe has got 58000+ rows and 26 columns. I will delete my rows for 58000+ rows.And delete rows if  more than 5% of variables are NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rowMeans` on a logical matrix created with `is.na`

```
df1[rowMeans(is.na(df1)) <= 0.5, , drop = FALSE]
```

In the above code, the `is.na(df1)` returns a logical matrix of TRUE (for NA) and FALSE (for non-NA), with `rowMeans`, we compute the percentage of TRUE values in row, check if it is less than or equal to 0.5 to create logical vector and subset the rows by using it as row index

Comment: dear friend,thanks for your help.But I have got  58000+ rows and 26 columns.So How to do it ?using for loop for it?

Comment: @OĞUZHANCALISKAN This should work for. those. case as well.  Have you tried?  Here, the conditions are for the whole dataset